# Cesium map loading slow

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm rendering cesium 3D map but he issue is it is loading slow, Can i reduce the lag time

i'm using these scripts :

```
<script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.84/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>

<link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.84/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[Sandcastle Link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

On live server sometimes it take 30 seconds to load the map.

Any solution, Thanks